# jQuery serialize adds additional field named '_' (underscore)

Tags: jquery, json, serialization

I use:

```
$.getJSON('addRecord.php', $('#addRecord').serialize())
```

to pass JSON data to a php function via AJAX. However, in addition to the fields of the form I get an field called '_', although I have done nothing whatever to the form. All form fields have names and IDs, and there is not very much after the  command.

This is the code of the form:

```
<form id='addRecord'>
    <div class='form-group' id='coTypeIdD'>
        <label for='coTypeId'>Type</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coTypeId' name='coTypeId' placeholder='Type'>
        <small id='coTypeIdM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coAccountIdD'>
        <label for='coAccountId'>Account</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coAccountId' name='coAccountId' placeholder='Account'>
        <small id='coAccountIdM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coIsPrimaryD'>
        <label for='coIsPrimary'>Primary?</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coIsPrimary' name='coIsPrimary' placeholder='Primary?'>
        <small id='coIsPrimaryM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coDescriptionD'>
        <label for='coDescription'>Description</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coDescription' name='coDescription' placeholder='Description'>
        <small id='coDescriptionM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coUserD'>
        <label for='coUser'>User</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coUser' name='coUser' placeholder='User'>
        <small id='coUserM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coSalutationD'>
        <label for='coSalutation'>Salutation</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coSalutation' name='coSalutation' placeholder='Salutation'>
        <small id='coSalutationM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coFirstNameD'>
        <label for='coFirstName'>First Name</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coFirstName' name='coFirstName' placeholder='First Name'>
        <small id='coFirstNameM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coLastNameD'>
        <label for='coLastName'>Last Name</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coLastName' name='coLastName' placeholder='Last Name'>
        <small id='coLastNameM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coTitleD'>
        <label for='coTitle'>Title</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coTitle' name='coTitle' placeholder='Title'>
        <small id='coTitleM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coDepartmentIdD'>
        <label for='coDepartmentId'>Department</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coDepartmentId' name='coDepartmentId' placeholder='Department'>
        <small id='coDepartmentIdM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coPreferredCommunicationD'>
        <label for='coPreferredCommunication'>Preferred Communication</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coPreferredCommunication' name='coPreferredCommunication' placeholder='Preferred Communication'>
        <small id='coPreferredCommunicationM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coPhoneD'>
        <label for='coPhone'>Extension</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coPhone' name='coPhone' placeholder='Extension'>
        <small id='coPhoneM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coEmailD'>
        <label for='coEmail'>Email</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coEmail' name='coEmail' placeholder='Email'>
        <small id='coEmailM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coMobileD'>
        <label for='coMobile'>Mobile </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coMobile' name='coMobile' placeholder='Mobile '>
        <small id='coMobileM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coSkypeD'>
        <label for='coSkype'>coSkype</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coSkype' name='coSkype' placeholder='coSkype'>
        <small id='coSkypeM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coFaxD'>
        <label for='coFax'>coFax</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coFax' name='coFax' placeholder='coFax'>
        <small id='coFaxM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coPhone2D'>
        <label for='coPhone2'>Alternate Phone</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coPhone2' name='coPhone2' placeholder='Alternate Phone'>
        <small id='coPhone2M' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group' id='coBirthdateD'>
        <label for='coBirthdate'>Birthday</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='coBirthdate' name='coBirthdate' placeholder='Birthday'>
        <small id='coBirthdateM' class='text-danger'></small>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here's what I get when I dump the `$_GET` in PHP:

[image: dump of $_GET]

Answer (score 1):

The `_` field is automatically added by jQuery to prevent caching the data. The `$.getJSON()` method is preconfigured, so you cannot change its behaviour, but you can use the `$.ajax()` method instead if you want to disable caching. Simply set its `cache` property to `false`.

Here is the explanation from [jQuery's docs for the `cache` property](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters.